# how to register custom model binder that take more than one argument + MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model binder as below

```
public PartyRoleModelBinder(IPartyRoleFactory prFactory)
    {
        PrFactory = prFactory;
        PRepo = pRepo;
        PrtRepo = prtRepo;
    }
protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
       //doing some work here
    }

    private IPartyRoleFactory PrFactory { get; set; }
    private IPartyRepository PRepo { get; set; }
    private IPartyRoleTypeRepository PrtRepo { get; set; }
```

I am registering it as below in global.asax.cs:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(PartyRole), new PartyRoleModelBinder(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPartyRoleFactory>()));
```

This is wokring fine till here.
Now My problem is I have to some more dependencies to my constructor, for ex:

```
public PartyRoleModelBinder(IPartyRoleFactory prFactory, IPartyRoleTypeRepository prtRepo, IPartyRepository pRepo)
    {
        PrFactory = prFactory;
        PRepo = pRepo;
        PrtRepo = prtRepo;
    }
```

But I am sure how to register this in global.asax.cs

If I use like below

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(PartyRole), new PartyRoleModelBinder(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPartyRoleFactory>()));
```

> it throws: Error   25  'PartyWeb.ModelBinders.PartyRoleModelBinder' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments  C:\d2\Apps\d2admin\Global.asax.cs   35  57  d2admin

Or

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(PartyRole), new PartyRoleModelBinder(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPartyRoleFactory, IPartyRepository, IPartyRoleTypeRepository>()));
```

> compile error: Error   25  The non-generic method 'System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver.GetService(System.Type)' cannot be used with type arguments  C:\d2\Apps\d2admin\Global.asax.cs   35  109 d2admin

can somebody advise how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to create a new instance of `PartyRoleModelBinder` that expects **3** parameters in it's (modified) constructor, but you're passing only 1 parameter and using `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` incorrectly along the way.

Try:

```
 var resolver = DependencyResolver.Current;
 IPartyRoleFactory roleFactory = resolver.GetService<IPartyRoleFactory>();
 IPartyRepository repo = resolver.GetService<IPartyRepository>();
 IPartyRoleTypeRepo typeRepo = resolver.GetService<IPartyRoleTypeRepository>();

 var partyRoleModelBinder = new PartyRoleModelBinder(roleFactory, typeRepo, repo);

 ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(PartyRole), partyRoleModelBinder);
```

Comment: Great, u shed the light, now this also can be done as:         ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(PartyRole), new PartyRoleModelBinder(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPartyRoleFactory>(),
                        DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPartyRoleTypeRepository>(), DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPartyRepository>()));

Answer (score 0):

I agree with haim770. 
another way of doing it is:

```
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(PartyRole), new PartyRoleModelBinder(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPartyRoleFactory>(),
                    DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPartyRoleTypeRepository>(), DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPartyRepository>()));
```